# this error shows to me when running my code, what the mean of "Could not find or load main class XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

### Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\DELL.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error: Could not find or load main class XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

---

Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:

- gradle.properties in project root directory
- gradle.properties in in GRADLE_USER_HOME directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "-" before the "XX". The command processor is assuming that the first argument that has no preceding "-" is the name of the class you want to execute.

Comment: The convention in StackOverflow is to click the tick/checkbox next to the answer to mark the answer as accepted; this helps future visitors to assess the answers. You don't need to say thanks!